# How do I change the HTML document displayed without it opening a window

Tags: javascript, html

so I made this ios PWA that has a button that changes the page: [the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owEGE.jpg) Works fine on safari, but when on the home screen, you get a window opened: [browser bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEHh4.jpg)
I kinda understand this since the code for the page changing is this:

```html
<script>
function crimson_home(){
    window.location.href='../crimson/home.html';
}
</script>
```

So I ask: How would I do this so the browser bar doesn't appear? I think it's something like the document method but I don't remember anything about it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The "address" bar is a security feature that you cannot hide. What you could do is replace the current contents of the document with the contents of another page through the use of an `iframe` or an AJAX call.

Comment: @ScottMarcus how would I do that? add the iframe and set it's contents to an html document, that I know, but how would I retrieve the document as a variable?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow